# How to collapse a structure after procedural destruction

Tags: physics, procedural-destruction

When considering this temple structure with procedural damage in pink:

[image]

How can I efficiently determine the collapse of such structure as below?

[image]

Even if the model is defined on a voxel grid, it would still require possibly wide-ranging searches for connected-ness?

In the 2D case, flood-filling and labeling disconnected components is probably doable, but what about the 3D-case?

Can this be done without traversing the entire world space, every frame -- which I imagine, wrecks havoc to a data cache?

Lastly, what is the technical term for this problem of "making stuff fall down after procedural damage?"

Comment: Whenever you feel like you have too much stuff to iterate over in detail, the answer is usually chunking. Group subsets of the data together in chunks, and store chunk-to-chunk connectivity (optionally at multiple levels of hierarchy - chunks of chunks of chunks...). Then you can localize updates to modified chunks, and the ones that depend on them in the event that their connectivity changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have done pretty much exactly this, in a 3d world. The key to not requiring processing the entire world is to focus on what is making the change; the removal of a voxel. The algorithm on removing a voxel (either by the player or procedurally*) would be as follows

1. Voxel is removed
2. Determine non air blocks previously connected to the removed voxel
3. Each of those blocks is marked as being in its own region (so up to 6 regions)
4. Iterate over the regions and expand them based on connections, **always process voxels closest to the removed voxel first**. If a region cannot expand mark it as "finished"
5. If a region expands into annother region combine them.

With this you very quickly end up with 1 of 2 results:

- The (up to 6) regions combine; no detachment occures
- All but one region is "finished" (i.e. can't expand anymore) and there is one unfinished region; the unfinished region remains part of the original world, all other regions detach.

As you can see in your diagram you'd very quickly loop round the arch and connect the 2 initial regions. on the other hand if the damage was a bit more extensive on the left you'd very quickly finish one of the two regions (detaching the top) and leaving the bottom (unfinished) region as part of the main world

*You can probably get clever when removing many voxels simultaneously to avoid repeated work but this is a good start